# Como fazer um select com uma array?

Tags: php

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho um array designado por $postos, este array $postos é um array que contem várias coisas, tais como: Trabalho, Jantar, Casa, Fora.

O que pretendo é fazer um select a uma tabela no banco de dados where posto=$postos, ou seja a todos os resultados, que estejam no array?

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

@EDIT:

```
 echo $postosstring;

    $procura1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM faturacoes where Status = 1 AND Data >= '$datainicial' AND Data <= '$datafinal' AND posto IN ('.$postosstring.')");

    // Total Contratos

    $resultset1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(contratos) as contratos FROM faturacoes where status='1' AND Data >= '$datainicial' AND Data <= '$datafinal' AND posto IN ('.$postosstring.')"); 

    $linha1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset1); 

    $soma1 = $linha1['contratos'];

    // Total Valor
$resultset2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(valor) as valor FROM faturacoes where Status = 1 AND Data >= '$datainicial' AND Data <= '$datafinal' AND posto IN ('.$postosstring.')");


$linha2= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset2); 

$soma2 = $linha2['valor'];
```

O meu SELECT não está a funcionar.

Comment: Explica melhor isso.

Comment: Pretendo fazer um select, onde o where é um array, basicamente é isso.

Comment: Mas o que contem esse `array`? Uma lista do mesmo campo? se for o caso, você pode utilizar `WHERE IN`.

Comment: Vou experimentar o where in.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi errado, parece que você quer criar uma query baseado em um array. Se for isso é simples, pode ser feito com uma iteração simples(foreach). Posta seu código PHP, se possível.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o `IN`.

Se a array for:

```
$array = ['Trabalho', 'Jantar', 'Casa', 'Fora'];
```

Você precisa passar isso para uma string, de maneira a ficar:

```
"Trabalho","Jantar","Casa","Fora"
```

Dessa forma você poderá usar `IN("Trabalho","Jantar","Casa","Fora")`.

> Considerando que não está usando o bind_param!

Para isso você tem várias e várias opções, que atingem o mesmo objetivo:

Você pode usar o `implode`:

```
$string = '"' . implode('","', $array) . '"';
// Resultado: "Trabalho","Jantar","Casa","Fora"
```

Se quiser pode fazer um loop *ou um array_map talvez.*

```
foreach($array as $i => $coisa){

   $string .= '"';
   $string .= mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $coisa);
   $string .= '"';
   $string .= $i + 1 < count($array) ? "," : "";

}
```

Então inserir no SQL:

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE coisa IN ('.$string.')');
```

Você pode adicionar outros *parâmetros* no `WHERE` normalmente.

```
mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM tabela where status = "1" AND Data >= "'.$datainicial.'" AND Data <= "'.$datafinal.'" AND coisa IN ('.$string.')');
```

---

Se preferir utilizar as aspas duplas `"` deve remover o `'`:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(valor) as valor FROM faturacoes where Status = 1 AND Data >= '$datainicial' AND Data <= '$datafinal' AND posto IN ($postosstring)");
```

O seu código atual com o `('.$postosstring.')` está fazendo isso: `'"Trabalho","Jantar","Casa","Fora"'` ao invés disso `"Trabalho","Jantar","Casa","Fora"`.

Comment: Não está a funcionar não me mostra nada.

Comment: Eu quero adicionar + com AND e nao funciona.

Comment: Aparentemente o problema é que está utilizando `IN ('.$postosstring.')"` o correto é sem o `'`. Troque por `IN ($postosstring)"`. Isso terá o mesmo efeito do código acima.

Comment: Tente utilizar o `mysqli_error($link)` após o primeiro `SELECT` para ver o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Perfeito! É isto mesmo que eu precisava.